Find all identifiers in a sourcefile related to a certain include / import
I want to find all symbols, typedefs, macros, etc.. that are imported into a source file via a specific #include or import statement. More conceptually speaking I want to find all identifiers that are "made known" by said import/header file. Check this out:
#include <iostream>
#include <span>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint> // the include in questions. If I select and <insert magic shortkey here> it should...

int main()
{
    // ... a lot of badly written source code
    std::vector<uint8_t> intvec = { 1, 2, 3, 4 }; // <-- hop here first, finds uint8_t
    auto vec_int_view = std::span(intvec);

    // ... heaps of badly written source code

    uint32_t my_int = 15; // <-- second hop lands you here for uint32_t

    // ... even more
}

I should be able to navigate back and forth in the file and find all the identifiers one by one.
This would be very useful to me since I could:

detect if an include / import is still needed
check what kind of changes a past merge request might have introduced when the source code changed (but import stayed).
...

Is there a facility in VS Code / extensions that provides this functionality? I'm also looking for the same in Python and Rust (that's why I mentioned import as well).

what do you mean by "token"? every token that's included is... a lot. also, you're aware that C++ has modules too, right?

Well let's leave c++ modules out of the question for now since they're anyway not uniformly implemented. As I defined I just want to scan through a file and jump through all tokens that are imported by a certain header file, e.g. types, variables, macros, etc...

I don't think you are using the right word for what you want. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases. please be precise.

@starball Thank you I've never dabbled on that site. That was actually an interesting read. So essentially token is not a term I should use here. Could I use "symbol"? If I understand correctly a symbol is everything that occupies an address in the final object file. That would probably come close to what I meant, although I also want to include namespaces, macros and types. Generally everything that was introduced by the header. If you have a suggestion on how I could rephrase my question such that it is more precise please go ahead.

maybe you want https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers. but that's just for C++. If you want the term from the VS Code extension API point of view, you're probably looking for https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#DocumentSymbol. you should decide whether you're asking specifically about C++ via cpptools, or something about the VS Code API and language-agnostic, or something else. then [edit] your question to specify it.

if you care specifically about C++, you should also be aware that some standard headers are specified to include other standard headers. see for example https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/string. then you should specify what you want in those cases. do you want to see usages of things transitively included by something directly included?

@starball That's a good question, but considering my use case above I would say everything that is directly or transitively included from the corresponding header. Again, conceptually "everything brought into awareness by a header file" (c++ specific).

okay. now say you include both the direct and transitive thing in the same thing. now what? do you want to get rid of the transitive include? do you want your tool to point out to you when this happens? also you forgot to [edit].

thanks for pointing that out, edited (I used the word "identifiers" - is this more descriptive?). I could imagine this would be nice to have for transitive includes, but mainly I want to get rid of includes that are not needed anymore in a specific source file and someone forgot to take it out. By showing all related identifiers this could be quickly done. E.g. maybe someone used iostream for log-debugging, and forgot to take it out. Do I know for sure it's not needed? I can't be sure because maybe there are other functions than cout and endl that are used.

have you heard of iwyu?

@starball Yes, but it doesn't work that nicely on our project. Idk why, but it includes a lot of odd headers deep from within the stdlib. Maybe it's just misconfigured. In any case, a tool like the one described is conceptually different in that it goes from header -> identifiers not the other way round.

I may suggest a solution that works with Xcode for this, but it would require you to build the solution with Xcode first. Lemme know if you're interested.

@EugeneDudnyk thanks for the offer but I didn't touch xcode ever. I'd be most interested in a solution in vscode or nvim.

You can use scip-clang to build the index database of your codebase. Then, you can use this approach to locally extract and analyze the information from that database.
There are scip indexing tools for other programming languages provided by sourcegraph, so you can benefit from uniform data format of the index database.
You can also explore sourcegraph platform itself, and its Cody AI that integrates into IntelliJ IDEs and into VSCode.
